# Convert nscala-time Datetime to java.util.Date

Tags: java, scala, jodatime, nscala-time

I am trying to cast com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime from nscala-time (a wrapper of joda-time) to java.util.Date

```
activeUntil.toDate()
```

But I get this error

> value toDate is not a member of Option[com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime]

Obviuosly is not the right way to do it. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `activeUntil` is an `Option[DateTime]` not `DateTime` itself. You can `map` it to `Date` and get providing some default value in case `Option` is empty like this

```
activeUntil.map(_.toDate).getOrElse(new Date())
```

I am not sure where did you get `activeUntil` from, but probably from a method that can fail to give you your `DateTime` this is why it returned an `Option` and forced you to handle the case when there is nothing to return.